# Show additional info in list of workflow runs on Github

Tags: github, github-actions

I need to display some additional information somewhere in this list. For example, something from workflow output or maybe some annotation.

But there is no even branch name :(

Can I achieve this?

If no, how can I change Name "Run Nuke Target" for specific run? This is manual run, so I have some inputs for it.

[image: Screenshot from Github]

Comment: Any luck with this? I would also like to show some custom info like values of input params for the specific workflow run.

Comment: No, as I investigated, it is not possible for now :(

Comment: If you want to show something from workflow inputs you can use `run-name` to make workflow name dynamic.

Comment: Thank you @webh, this is solution for now